# Map dropdown list with json content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file that I wish to access, based on HTML option value attribute.

I can access the data, and pick stuff out, but like I wrote earlier, I like to do it based on what is chosen from the list.

So I wanna map option value attribute with p in the json file.

So my list looks like this

```
<div>
  <select id="places">
    <option>Choose city...</option>
    <option value="Place1">Place1</option>
    <option value="Place2">Place2</option>
    <option value="Place3">Place3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  data: [{
      date: "2018031406",
      p: [{
          lon: -7.777,
          lat: xxxxx,
          precip - intensity: 0.046875,
          pressure - sealevel: 100225.25,
          temperature: 4.34227,
          wind - dir: 122.00003,
          wind - speed: 13.022041,
          weather - symbol: 3
        },
        {
          lon: -6.666,
          lat: xxxx,
          precip - intensity: 0.046875,
          pressure - sealevel: 100230.75,
          temperature: 3.77977,
          wind - dir: 120.87503,
          wind - speed: 13.006416,
          weather - symbol: 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      date: "2018031407",
      p: [{
          lon: -7.777,
          lat: xxxxx,
          precip - intensity: 0.046875,
          pressure - sealevel: 100225.25,
          temperature: 4.34227,
          wind - dir: 122.00003,
          wind - speed: 13.022041,
          weather - symbol: 3
        },
        {
          lon: -6.666,
          lat: xxxxx,
          precip - intensity: 0.046875,
          pressure - sealevel: 100230.75,
          temperature: 3.77977,
          wind - dir: 120.87503,
          wind - speed: 13.006416,
          weather - symbol: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So the layout is based on what time it is, so I have this set up in jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var location = 'folder/folder2/folder3/area/area.json';


  jQuery.getJSON(location, function(json) {


    function pad2(n) {
      return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n
    }

    var date_now = new Date();

    date_test = date_now.getFullYear().toString() + pad2(date_now.getMonth() + 1) + pad2(date_now.getDate()) + pad2(date_now.getHours());


    var index = json.data.findIndex(function(item, i) {
      return item.date === date_test

    });

    //This I can use to see which index number is the current hour
    //I have weather data a couple of hours backwards, and alot forward (in time).

    //console.log(index);


    //Manually fetch data

    /*--------------------Temperature--------------------------------------*/

    //Lets say - index+1 is  date: "2018031407" and p[1] is the second p from json file - which indicates the hour now +1 (date) and area (p).

    var some_temp = JSON.stringify(json.data[index + 1].p[1]["temperature"]);

    //console.log(some_temp);

    var some_temp2 = Math.round(some_temp);

    console.log(some_temp2);

    jQuery(".div_temp").prepend(some_temp2);

    /*------------------------Temperature ends----------------------------------------*/


  });
});
```

How should I approach the task? Having difficulties getting on. I'm a noob at this.

An exaple would be that Place1 should equal p[0], Place2 equal p[1] etc...

Comment: It’s not clear what your question is. If you need to use numbers, then just use numbers? `value="0"` and so on, then they match up?

Comment: Yes that would be perfect....but how do implement it...so if I choose Place1 which has value 0, how would it iterate through the temperature section?

Comment: I mean so it would change p[1] in temperature section to p[0].

Comment: Your current build finds the correct data field based on having the "exact" same time. In the case that the date in your JSON is not == the current date time, what do you want to happen? Go to the next date? Got to the closest date?

Comment: The only thing that should change in the temperature section is p which matches an area, which should match an option in the list.

Comment: I find the time (which is now), and then I just write index+1 (one hour ahead) or index-1 one hour backwards. This does the job....I just wanna iterate through the p section, which is an area, because i have 95 of them.

Comment: p section/array in the json file is p[0], p[1], p[2]...p[94]. These I wanna iterate through....so I  set everything up -- temperature, weather-symbol, pressure-sealevel and so forth, for every hour: index-6, index-5, index-4...index, index+1, index+2...index+48. Then my plan is to just iterate though the p value...which should match the value from option value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using...

```
//Put the json file to a variable
var location = 'folder/script.json';

//make a function called json, using the locaction variable
jQuery.getJSON(location, function(json) {


        jQuery("select").change(function(){

              jQuery(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){

                var optionValue = jQuery(this).attr("value");

                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < JSON.stringify(json.data[index].p.length); ++i) {
                  //console.log(i);

                  if (i == optionValue) {
                    console.log(optionValue);



                    var some_temp = JSON.stringify(json.data[index].p[i]["temperature"]);
                    var some_temp2 = Math.round(some_temp);
                    jQuery(".temp_div").html(some_temp2);


                }
              }
              });
            }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, you first need to pick the right data set based on the date property and then you will filter it again based on the place.

You can do this by using the filter method as your data is in an array.

```
var yourJson = "{}"; // your json variable
var dataForDate = yourJson.data.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.date == '2018031406'; // your filter criteria
});
```

`dataForDate` will be another array and if you have only one matching property, you can access it by `dataForDate[0]`

After this you can implement the same filter function if you want to filter location data based on some property.

If you want to loop through all the `p`s you can do the following

```
$.each( dataForDate[0].p, function( index, value ){
    // you can access all the properties here
    // example
    // value.lat
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! You pushed me in the right direction!